# LOR and sinat chinam or lashon hara

Tags: rabbis, chabad, derech-eretz-manners, lashon-hara-slander, bein-adam-lachavero

Recently the rav at my local schul made a highly innapropriate remark on Facebook which would be considered lashon hara as well as sinat chinam. As the schul is a shlichut of Chabad (it is the only fromm schul within walking distance) the rav is not appointed by the community. What is the proper recourse to such an action and does Chabad have any way to deal with such public aveirot?

Usually, this issue would fall under CYLOR, however, that is not really an option in this case.

Comment: So you resort to CY non-Local Random Group of People??? There is no other Rabbi you can ask?

Comment: If the question is about if "Chabad have any way to deal with" this, why not use the [Chabad tag](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chabad)?

Comment: Also, why not just [ask Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/asktherabbi/default_cdo/jewish/Ask-the-Rabbi.htm)?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest sending a message to the Chabad headquarters.

> Contact Us
>   Lubavitch World Headquarters
>   770 Eastern Parkway
>   Brooklyn, New York 11213
>
> Phone: 718 774.4000
>   Fax 718 774.2718
>   Email: info@lubavitch.com